# SwiftUI Binding is not getting set within the same block

Tags: swiftui

**Under what conditions would a @State assignment not get set within the same code block?**

I am battling a SwiftUI state issue and have found that in a block executed within a sheet closure, a view @State object is not retaining its value immediately after being set. If you look at the screenshot of the debugger break. The line directly above the green breakpoint sets the self.imageSource @State variable to selectedSelectedSource which is an enum. You can see in the watches that the value of selectedSource (First blue line) is ".library." Yet the value of self.imageSource (second blue line) is ".none"

I have tried multiple variations of this sheet code using all the patterns presentationMode, @binding the show variable, callbacks, asyncs and every time the @State imageSource never gets set. Ironically if I use an action sheet, it works without issue.

Please I am looking for answers pertaining to the mechanics of @State that would explain this behaviour.

[image: Break Point]

Comment: The issue probably has more to do with the mechanics of the .sheet() than the @State. The code within a sheet closure doesn't update with the view state. Could you provide a minimum reproducible code example?

Comment: Would you provide your code or minimal reproducible example?